# Office 365 (SharePoint Online) C# Authentication from custom application using tokens

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I have a custom c# windows forms application. How can I authenticate to Office 365 SharePoint Online in order to issue HttpWebRequest to customer web-sites using ACS tokens.

User will provide username and password and based on that I want to generate an ACS token that will allow the application to make requests on customer web-site. Also I want to be able to regenerate the token if it's expired, without reprompting username and password if possible.

if this will be a provider hosted app, then no problem is easy to do it but how can I achieve this from a custom application which is not a SharePoint app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to rewrite the code which supports `[SharePointContextFilter]` attribute which does the work in provider hosted app. Or port your web forms application to a provider hosted app template and deploy.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? Which part of the code you refer to? Do you mean the `[SharePointContextFilter]` attribute itself?

Comment: classes SharePointContextFilterAttribute and SharePointContext in the provider hosted app which is autogenerated and handles all the dirty work of authentication and authorization of the app in SharePoint context. You will have to recreate the same framework if you want to make it custom.. I would suggest you port it as provider hosted app which saves you all this work..